# The Inbox thingie crashes Safari on my ipod

Tags: support, bug

For about a day and a half now, whenever I try to open the Inbox thingy on the top left corner, my iPod's Safari browser dies.

This is an up-to-date iPod/safari. I am not able to provide mucho more information, sadly, as this thing is pretty obtuse.

Comment: I've had a similar experience while using iOS in the past few weeks, except that the app/browser doesn't crash; it simpy won't ever load the inbox.

Comment: It might not be easy to determine what it is, I'm afraid, as it is working fine on Safari on my iPad.

Comment: What happens when you try to view your inbox from a non-MathJax-enabled site like [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/)?